# Why isn't the max-height working on table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Can someone please explain to me why the **max-height** is not working on table element?

Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/PYDf2/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

Read the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights).

Set the table to `display: block` if you want to force `max-height`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the table within a DIV to make the max-height working. As bookcasey mentioned  max-height for table is undefined in the specification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the display.
Try 
    display: block;